# Can I perform navigate to a screen without going though a Navigation bar?

Tags: shiny

I have developed an application with Menu and Submenu system using navbarpage and tab panels under navbarMenu.

If I want to go to a specific screen I have to go through the Navigation Manu.

But, can I program the Navigation without that? For e.g. If I am on screen ProcessManagement->ModelRunMonitor and if I click an action button on this screen, I want to go to the screen DataManagement->ModelData without actually navigating through the menu.

Also I want to get the context from previous screen and depending on that context show the data on the next screen.

Can I do it in R Shiny?

Please see sample screens from my application below.